# Connected To Wifi Network; No Internet Acess (iPad)

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, safari

On my school iPad while I had a few tabs open my internet all was all fine and handy dandy but then all of a sudden I lost wifi connection (which my iPad does pretty often so I'm angry but used to it) but when I connected to my home's wifi connection and I went back on safari to my tabs, it said my ipad isn't connected to the internet suggesting I didn't have my wifi on even though I checked and my wifi network had it's blue check mark meaning I was connected. And sometimes it would take a long moment to load it would then say 
"Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding."
If I refresh the page a second time if I get this message it once more says
"because your iPad is not connected to the internet." even though when I check my wifi it says I'm connected and shows the blue check mark. Even if I forget the network and renew the lease the same thing happens. I went onto Google on my computer and iPhone "wifi connected but no internet acess iPad" because I can't find the answer I need and most of the answers I don't understand. I'm only 13 years old in 8th grade jr high so I don't understand anything about stuff like DHCP or BootP or Static and how they work and I don't know what is DNS and such. I don't know exacty what resetting my network settings does and what I've read about network settings reset gets rid of stuff like VPN or MMS or APN. I'm trying to find something easy for me to understand and something helpful but not complicated that you need to be a professional coder or something to understand. 
My regular iPad my family and I use, my computer (which isn't Apple) and my iPhone work perfectly fine with wifi. (Well, my iphone is new and I literally just got it yesterday and it's my first phone ever so of course no problems yet.) I tried forgetting the network after renewing the lease and that does no good either. Everytime I check the wifi network says it's connected and has the  blue checkmark and even the little lock icon but it always says it's not connected when I reload the page on safari. Can someone please explain exactly what's going on but explain in a way a jr high student girl (who doesn't know the complicated stuff and difficult steps to fixing issues like these well at all) like me can understand? 
(Oh, and I apologize for any grammar mistakes and whatnot just to say before I start feeling guilty over them afterwards in case I made any.)
I'd really love the help!
In case I need to include info on the school iPad, it's a iPad air with the 9.2.1 software update and IOS 8. 
Just including this info in case it's important!

Answer (score 1):

At the time your iPad is showing no network or the page is not loading, please run speedtest.net or similar app to see whether your incoming internet signal is working or not. Just because your iPad has a good connection to the wifi router in your house doesn't ensure you connectivity of internet. If that works then quit all tabs in safari and physically close the safari app. Restart and try again. Sometimes the link in safari expires or has some error. Try any popular website.

If on the other hand at that very moment your alternate device, be it your pc or phone is connected on same wifi network and the page is loading then it's evidently a problem with your iPad wifi card. Quit all apps manually, reboot your iPad, delete saved networks and restart your iPad. Try again if that too fails contact apple care for a hardware fix.